# Ignoring part of string based on position of underscore

Tags: regex, matlab, regex-negation

I have a list of experimental conditions that look like the left column in this table:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Input                                    | Output                    |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
| ID1_sWT_c1_ext_x1                        | sWT                       |
| ID29_s3KO_pNodC_VcCDA_c3_ext_x1          | s3KO_pNodC_VcCDA          |
| ID47_s3KO_pTet_NodC_VcCDA_50ng_c3_ext_x1 | s3KO_pTet_NodC_VcCDA_50ng |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I would like to get the output in the right column using regex (this is required!). Basically ignore everything before, and including, the first underscore (`_`) and ignore everything after the third to last underscore including the underscore. I have tried a bit myself, and came up with a solution that splits everything into two groups and ignores before the first underscore:

```
 (?<=\_).*[A-Za-z0-9_]*(_[^_]*_[^_]*_[^_]*)$
```

Now I am however stuck and was wondering whether anyone knew a good solution.

I am working with Matlab. I need it to make a figure that groups all biological replicates (denoted `c1`, `c2` and `c3`) together.

Comment: What language are you working with?

Comment: Ah, I did not realize that mattered. But I am working with Matlab.

Comment: The data comes from a text file. I am working with a GUI that someone wrote on top of it and I do not (and maybe can not) know whether it is read at the time it is needed or stored in an intermediate MATLAB table. my guess is that it is read from file.

Comment: How is the text file being read? I can provide you with a MATLAB demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following expression:

```
(?<=_).*(?=_c\d)
```

- `(?<=_)` Lookbehind for `_`.
- `.*` Match anything.
- `(?=_c\d)` Lookahead for `_c` followed by a digit.

Regex demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/ZW1W1W/1).

Comment: You absolute hero! I did not think of the lookahead after c thing. Thanks!